# AngularJS directive - avoiding jQuery-esque architecture

Tags: jquery, html, angularjs, dom, angularjs-directive

I'm trying to create a directive for a gallery, similar to the *People* tile in Windows 8. Meaning - the directive will swap images randomly within a matching 2x2 or 3x3 grid (depending on the amount of images). For this question's simplicity's sake, let's assume there will always be enough images to swap and no duplicates.

The gallery must be highly optimized for visual performance - so far I've managed to slim it down to a single CSS operation and re-render (not a single DOM reflow!). Therefore, using `ng-repeat` is totally overkill here.

This directive is also a "set and forget" one. Meaning the model will not change and require removing or adding items to the gallery. So there's really no need for something like `ng-repat` here.

Right now my HTML looks like this (for a 2x2 tile):

```
<div> <!-- link $element -->
  <img src="" alt="">
  <img src="" alt="">
  <img src="" alt="">
  <img src="" alt="">
</div>
```

I'm trying to wrap my head around adding the gallery DOM to the tile, within the link function of course. Right now I'm generating images and appending them to the container `div`:

```
var images = [],
     $img;
 for (var i = 0; i < gallerySize; i++) {
     $img = $('<img>').appendTo($el);
     images.push($img);
 }
```

And my timer loop takes care of swapping the images. I'm only worried about what if my template gets more complex, or if I introduce some CSS animations which require me to change my template. It feels like this is drifting away from "The Angular Way". Am I giving myself a hard time here? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the main thing you don't seem to be using is a template in the directive definition. In fact, unless you really need to, you often don't need to manually touch the DOM in a directive, especially if all you're doing is using the directive to put in some HTML that reacts to some standard events in some way (e.g. changing an images based on a timer or a click).

```
<div class="gallery">
  <img ng-repeat="image in images" ng-src="{{image.src}}" />
</div>
```

Then in the controller of the directive (or the link function I think), you can put in your logic, just as you would for any business-type controller:

```
$scope.swapImage = function(i) {
  // Do something
}
```

To address your use of the DOM:

> Therefore, using ng-repeat is totally overkill here.

Unless you've got 100s (/1000s ?) of images on screen at any one time, I would use the features of Angular: templates, with controllers and directives, such as ng-repeat, rather than manual DOM manipulation. This is the "Angular Way": it should be less brittle to a more complex template, and be generally clearer as you have a template that explains exactly what the html will be, rather than having it slightly buried in several lines of code.

Although you say you don't need it, you might want to later put in some 2 way data binding in the template. If not the images themselves, then maybe some associated state of the images. Say, zoomed-in, or something else a bit "view" based. This would be more tricky if you've constructed the DOM manually: you'll have to put in some calls to $compile I suspect. All possible, but you might as well have just created a single templates with a few references to `$scope` variables.

Also: I see you have an `id` attribute in the example. Using these can be quite un-Angular, as it's effectively a global identifier, and might mean you can't have different instances of the gallery on the same page at the same time.

Comment: I like this answer, but since he claims the model doesn't change then a nice compromise might be to use something like this: https://github.com/Pasvaz/bindonce which is an implementation of ng-repeat which doesn't have nearly as many watches.

Comment: I think that's good, although for a maximum of 9 images, I think the performance benefits would be negligible?

Comment: Probably pretty negligible. The 'angular way' and performance just don't always align. Binding is magical but you sacrifice some performance for its power.

Comment: @JonathanRowny @Micahl Charemza I only put the ID there to make it clear this is the directive container - perhaps it was redundant. I'll look into `Bindonce`. It looks promising on first look. Just to clarify: maximum of 9 images *displayed*, but the model might contain 10s, if not 100s of them. To summarize, I certainly don't want to go against the grain here, but wish to keep it standard for maintainability and higher quality code. Thank you both for the comprehensive answer and comments.

Comment: I hope this answer will serve as useful guidelines for others :)

Comment: Instead of assuming it's going to be slow, you should try it and measure. Usually the areas I think will be slow end up being very cheap, and some random operation I didn't even think of is the actual bottleneck.